# Is it possible to install application from playstore in device farm?

Tags: java, android, junit, appium-android, aws-device-farm

I am using AppiumDriver to install android application on Amazon device farm.
And i have tested this in real device and it's working perfectly fine but when I am putting same code into Device Farm at that time it want work. It want open play store application and get below error.

> Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: connect timed out Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
> Tests failed

Please check below code for it.

```
@Before
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "FA8351A00767");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Google Pixel 2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
    if (!isShopperAppAvailable()) {
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.vending");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
                "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
    } else {
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "your application package");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
                "your app's launcher activity");
    }
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
 }

public boolean isShopperAppAvailable() {
    boolean isShopperAppAvailable = false;
    if (driver != null) {
        isShopperAppAvailable = driver.isAppInstalled("your application package");
    }
    return isShopperAppAvailable;
}

@Test
public void testGooglePlayApp() throws InterruptedException {
    if (!isShopperAppAvailable()) {
        String appName = "Search your application";
        driver.findElementById("com.android.vending:id/0_resource_name_obfuscated").click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElementByXPath(
                "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.EditText")
                .sendKeys(appName);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.LinearLayout"))
                .click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        MobileElement installButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath(
                "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.Button");
        installButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } else {
        System.out.println("open your app and do something");
    }

}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a relevant stack trace showcasing the issue? It's possible Google Play was not accessible during your test run.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to install your Google account onto Device Farm devices before downloading apps from the app store. I have developed sample code for doing both of these things (installing your account and downloading apps) here: https://github.com/aristeia/GoogleAccountSignInScript . Please give this a try and let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: The link is no longer working. Could you provide us with the answer in this thread or update the link?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Artur. I have updated the link to https://github.com/aristeia/GoogleAccountSignInScript